# Kate switches to RTL input and I can't get back to LTR

Tags: 10.04, kate

This has happened a couple of times (also to my boss) - but once in a long while, Kate will just switch over to right-to-left input.

We've searched for the menu command or keyboard combination that triggers this so that we can return to left-to-right input, but we've pretty much had to resort to restarting Kate.

What is the command for this switchover?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting bitten by [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=246162) bug.

Some observations from the comments:

- It seems to be not triggered by a shortcut.
- It might not be a bug in Kate, but a bug in some Qt component.
- It seems to not switch from LTR to RTL, instead it messes up the cursor position.
- A workaround seems to be saving, then reloading the document (keyboard shortcut: F5).

Comment: That workaround is much better than restarting the whole application :) thanks